# Calling Runtime.gc() in onLowMemory method

Tags: java, android, performance

Should we use `Runtime.gc()` or `System.gc()` for clearing memory (manual garbage collection) in production code in `onLowMemory()` method in Application class?

Comment: No, cause on low memory the System already tried to GC, you need to clear resources instead

Comment: @AesSedai101 The question is whether he should call either of them, not which.

Comment: @hemant-parmar Sorry for misunderstanding, I meant to ask whether we should use Runtime.gc() (or System.gc()) in `onLowMemory()` or not.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bad practice, using `System.gc()` is not meaning you use manually gc it's only hint to jvm to wipe off garbage. Better to not use this method like `finalize()` in `Object`, both of them not provide any guarantee. In javadoc of `Application` said that system will perform gc after returning from this method and given way to do it in the right manner.

> You should implement this method to release any caches or other
>   unnecessary resources you may be holding on to. The system will
>   perform a garbage collection for you after returning from this method.

[Application javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onLowMemory())

So when you use `System.gc()` in `onLowMemory()` method after return from this method, will be another garbage collection effort. From hint in javadoc it's better to lost link to caches in example `List<Object> bigCache = null;`  after method end will be garbage collection that pick up that cache list and memory will free.

Answer (score 2):

No. From the Javadoc:

> You should implement this method to release any caches or other unnecessary resources you may be holding on to. The system will perform a garbage collection for you after returning from this method.

Answer (score 0):

For clear the memory you can call both inside `onLowMemory()`

Both are same. `System.gc()` is effectively equivalent to `Runtime.gc()`. `System.gc()`internally calls `Runtime.gc()`.

only difference is `System.gc()` is a class method where as `Runtime.gc()` is an instance method. So, `System.gc()` is more convenient.

Hope you get it.

Comment: Also, calling `System.gc()` once yields much different results than `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { System.gc(); }` does...